Understanding the proof of Fenn-Rourke Theorem
Fenn-Rourke Theorem states that Framed links can be transformed into each other by Kirby moves if and only if they can be done by Fenn- Rourke moves. I'm trying to understand the proof of it in V.V.Prasolov and A.B.Sossinsky's book $\textit{Knots, Links, braids and 3-manifolds}$, chapter 19.5. Here I copy parts of its proof.


My question is, in the last paragraph of the proof, How do we get 19.12(b) from 19.12(a)? It seems to me that $K_2$ can not pass through the middle cyclinder.

I think I know what's going on here,  first we use Fenn- Rourke moves to untie the knot, then since $K_1$ is a trivial knot , we can "add" it to $K_2$, then we use Fenn-Rourke moves to tie it back which is what the picture supposed to mean. The picture is misleading. Am I right?

That sounds also right! You do the moves in different order, I've added an answer explaining how they perform their moves in the drawings.

Starting from Figure 19.12 (a): For the first move ignore the $K_1$-ribbon (push it to the bottom) and bring $K_2$ close and parallel to the cylinder.
We can now apply the move from Fig. 19.11.b and obtain the loop $K_1'$ with +1-framing together with the twisting of the cylinder and $K_2$. This is the reason why in Figure 19.12 (b) the strand of $K_2$ suddenly wraps around the cylinder.
Finally, using the original $K_1$-strand to apply the move of Fig. 19.11.(a) twists back the cylinder in the original position and the end result is Fig. 19.12.(c).
Hope this helps! (might add drawings later if it doesn't)
